# Машина состояний для сохранения id видео и текста в чате

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть машина состояний для того чтобы ловить id видео, но нужно чтоб она сохраняла последний текст в чате и собственно далее сохраняла ссылку на видео.

```
class FSMdonload(StatesGroup):
    video = State()
    idprofile = State()
    number_qwestion = State()
@dp.message_handler(commands="Видеоответ", state=None)
async def fsm_donload_video(message: types.Message):
    await FSMdonload.video.set()
    test = message.text
    print(test)
    await message.reply('Нажмите на скрепку и запишите видеоответ')


# Ловим id video and id profile
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['video'] ,state=FSMdonload.video)
async def load_video(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['video'] = message.video.file_id
        data['idprofile'] = message.from_id
        data['number_qwestion'] = message.text
        
    await message.reply('Видео ответ принят')
    await sql_add_videobase(state)  # выводил в базу
    await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было в класс добавить еще одно состояние

```
@dp.message_handler(state=FSMdonload.number_qwestion)
async def safe_qwestion(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number_qwestion'] = message.text
    await FSMdonload.next()
```